Angular keeps returning form control as required, when there are no validators
Here is what I do, I'm also using a deepCopy to make sure no strange pass by reference things are happening
const formGroup = this.allowances()
    formGroup.removeControl('allowanceEndDate')
    const newFormGroup = deepCopy(formGroup)

    newFormGroup.addControl(
      'allowanceEndDate',
      new FormControl(null, {
      nonNullable: false,
      validators: []})
    )

    console.log(newFormGroup)

I keep getting this - required is still set to true... when it should just say errors: null:

And the raw validator.required is also not there, so still don’t understand why further up it says required=true, is there another flag I need to programmatically set?

UPDATE
Whatever I try, I just cannot remove error {required: true}
  const lastEndDateControl = lastformGroup?.get('allowanceEndDate')
    console.log(lastEndDateControl)
    if (lastEndDateControl) {
      lastEndDateControl.removeValidators(Validators.required);
      const err = lastEndDateControl.errors
      console.log(err)
      clearControlError(lastEndDateControl)
      lastEndDateControl.reset()
      console.log(lastEndDateControl)
      //lastEndDateControl.updateValueAndValidity();
    }

    function clearControlError( control: AbstractControl ): void {
      const err = control.errors;
      if (err) {
        delete err['required'];
        if (!Object.keys(err).length) {
          control.setErrors(null);
        } else {
          control.setErrors(err);
        }
      }
    }


I suspect that you might apply the required attribute in the <input> element. Can you reproduce it in StackBlitz? Thanks.

the status of your formcontrol is invalid for that you can write this code for specific control :
allowanceEndDate.reset();

then the status of control will be valid and errors will be null.
